# Value of $\arctan(x),...$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

If we have the value of $\sin(x)$ then we can find the value of $\cos(x),\tan(x),\cot(x),\sec(x),\csc(x)$. If we have the value of $\arcsin(x)$ then we can find the value of $\arccos(x)$, because
$$\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$ but can also we find the value of $\arctan(x),\text{arccot}(x),\text{arcsec}(x),\text{arccsc}(x)$?

Comment: In other words, you want representations for all inverse trigonometric functions in terms of $\arcsin$ evaluated at the same point?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle\arcsin x=y$

$\displaystyle\implies(i) x=\sin y$

and $(ii)-\frac\pi2 \le y\le \frac\pi2$  as the [principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) value of lies in $\in\left[-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2\right]$

and $(iii)-1\le x\le 1$

Again, $\displaystyle\text{arccsc}(x)$ is defined if $x\ge1$ or $x\le-1$

So, we need $x=\pm1$ to have both $\displaystyle\text{arccsc}(x), \arcsin(x)$ defined whence both equal to sign$(x)\displaystyle\frac\pi2$

Similarly, for $\displaystyle\text{arcsec}(x)$

If $\arctan x=z, x=\tan z$ Again we have  $x=\sin y\implies \tan z=\sin y$

I don't there is any elegant method to find $z(=\arctan x)$ in a simple form